# Feature testing issues in laravel

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-8

I wrote a test for my controller and  its giving this error for Create

> "Expected response status code [201] but received 302.Failed asserting that 201 is identical to 302"

and this error for Update

> "Expected response status code [201] but received 405.Failed asserting that 201 is identical to 405".

```php
public function testCreateAssetSuccessfully(): void
{
    $user = $this->createUser();

    $file = UploadedFile::fake()
        ->create('photo.jpeg', 200, 'image/jpeg')
        ->size(1000);

    $payload = [
        'name' => 'Audi',
        'description' => 'world class',
        'price' => '4000',
        'model' => 'Bent104',
        'brand' => fake()->name(),
        'year' => 2000,
        'gas_type' =>'fuel',
        'transmission_' =>'manual',
        'images' => [$file, $file],
        'city' => 'Berlin',
        'state_id' => '1',
        'country_id' => '115',
        'condition' => 'new',
        'avalability_status' => 'pending',
    ];


    $response = $this->actingAs($user)
        ->post('/api/v1/assets', $payload);

    $response->assertStatus(201)
        ->assertJsonPath('message', 'Successfully Created Assets')
        ->assertJsonPath('success', true);
}
```

Comment: Add `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` at the beginning of the test (of exactly before you call the endpoint) and it will throw the real error, maybe authentication

Comment: Nordmann_Loki asks: *"Is the route correctly set as `Route::post`? Or is it set as `Route::get` in your routes file?"*